# Difference diamagnetism and antiferromagnetism

Tags: condensed-matter, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

What are the main differences between diamagnets and antiferromagnets? I found out that $\chi_\text{dia} < 0$ and $\chi_\text{antiferro} > 0$, but as far as I understood, they behave pretty much the same when they are exposed to magnetic fields at temperature's above the antiferromagnet's Néel temperature.

Could someone please enlighten me on this topic?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.irm.umn.edu/hg2m/hg2m_b/hg2m_b.html#antiferromagnetism) you find a simple explanation. Key points:

- Diamagnetic substances are composed of atoms which have no net magnetic moments (ie., all the orbital shells are filled and there are no unpaired electrons). However, when exposed to a magnetic field, a negative magnetization is produced and thus the susceptibility is negative.

  - Antiferromagnetism: The magnetic structure is composed of two magnetic sublattices (called A and B). For an antiferromagnet the A and B sublattice moments are exactly equal but opposite. The net moment is zero.